# Flink[1.3.0] application doesn't write anything on the hdfs state backend

Tags: apache-flink

I have a simple stateful flink application and I have enabled checkpoint, I would the checkpoint data writtern to hdfs: /flink-savepoint/FlinkKafkaTest-checkpoint/${job_id}. When the application starts running for a while, I checked the directory, and this directoy indeed exists on HDFS, but there is nothing under it(no chk_xx directories).

Also, I checked the log of TaskManager, looks it indeed that the checkpoint has been finined periodically(see the output: `snapshotState is called and checkpointComplete, checkpointId: 1`3)

The command that I kicks off the application is:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 6 ...
```

My code is below the TaskManager log, I would ask where the problem is and save me out, thanks!

```
18:48:40.685 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - Invoking async call Checkpoint Trigger for Source: Custom Source (1/4) (019e4a7ece0baeb6e1d1e6a5c0a0a4b5). on task Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.685 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - Creating FileSystem stream leak safety net for Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.685 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Starting checkpoint (13) FULL_CHECKPOINT on task Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.685 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Received barrier from channel 0
18:48:40.685 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Starting stream alignment for checkpoint 13.
snapshotState is called
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Received barrier from channel 1
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Received barrier from channel 2
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Received barrier from channel 3
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Received all barriers, triggering checkpoint 13 at 1572346120678
18:48:40.686 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend - DefaultOperatorStateBackend snapshot (File Stream Factory @ hdfs://hacluster/user/ioc/flink-savepoint/FlinkKafkaTest-checkpoint/11c79683b332737eb1fb0ae84ff91e71, synchronous part) in thread Thread[Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4),5,Flink Task Threads] took 1 ms.
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - End of stream alignment, feeding buffered data back
18:48:40.686 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Finished synchronous checkpoints for checkpoint 13 on task Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer - Size of buffered data: 0 bytes
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Starting checkpoint (13) FULL_CHECKPOINT on task Sink: Unnamed (1/6)
18:48:40.686 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Source: Custom Source (1/4) - finished synchronous part of checkpoint 13.Alignment duration: 0 ms, snapshot duration 0 ms
18:48:40.686 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.686 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Source: Custom Source (1/4) - finished asynchronous part of checkpoint 13. Asynchronous duration: 0 ms
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Finished synchronous checkpoints for checkpoint 13 on task Sink: Unnamed (1/6)
18:48:40.686 [Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Sink: Unnamed (1/6) - finished synchronous part of checkpoint 13.Alignment duration: 0 ms, snapshot duration 0 ms
18:48:40.686 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Sink: Unnamed (1/6) - finished asynchronous part of checkpoint 13. Asynchronous duration: 0 ms
18:48:40.928 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManager - Receiver ConfirmCheckpoint 13@1572346120678 for 019e4a7ece0baeb6e1d1e6a5c0a0a4b5.
18:48:40.928 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - Invoking async call Checkpoint Confirmation for Source: Custom Source (1/4) on task Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.928 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManager - Receiver ConfirmCheckpoint 13@1572346120678 for 30ee4b703a06714825ec5fa1d2324b5a.
18:48:40.928 [Async calls on Source: Custom Source (1/4)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Notification of complete checkpoint for task Source: Custom Source (1/4)
18:48:40.928 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - Invoking async call Checkpoint Confirmation for Sink: Unnamed (1/6) on task Sink: Unnamed (1/6)
checkpointComplete, checkpointId: 13
18:48:40.928 [Async calls on Sink: Unnamed (1/6)] DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask - Notification of complete checkpoint for task Sink: Unnamed (1/6)
18:48:42.075 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@dggtsp370-or:32586]
18:48:42.077 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher - Received heartbeat rsp from [akka.tcp://flink@dggtsp370-or:32586]
18:48:42.624 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] DEBUG org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnTaskManager - Sending heartbeat to JobManager
```

The main method is defined as follows:

```
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

object CheckpointTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.enableCheckpointing(10 * 1000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    env.addSource(new CheckpointSourceFunction).setParallelism(4).print()
    val path = "hdfs:///flink-savepoint/FlinkKafkaTest-checkpoint"
    val backend = new FsStateBackend(path)
    env.setStateBackend(backend)
    env.execute("CheckpointTest")
  }
}
```

and the CheckpointSoruceFunction is defined as:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ListState, ListStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.{CheckpointListener, FunctionInitializationContext, FunctionSnapshotContext}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.{RichParallelSourceFunction, SourceFunction}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class CheckpointSourceFunction extends RichParallelSourceFunction[String] with CheckpointedFunction with CheckpointListener {
  @volatile
  var running: Boolean = true
  var count: Long = 0
  var countState: ListState[Long] = null
  var subId: Int = 0


  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    subId = this.getRuntimeContext.getIndexOfThisSubtask + 1
  }

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit = {
    while (running) {
      ctx.collect(s"Hello-$count")
      count = count + 1
      Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    running = false
  }

  override def snapshotState(context: FunctionSnapshotContext): Unit = {
    println("snapshotState is called")
    countState.clear()
    countState.add(count)
  }

  override def initializeState(context: FunctionInitializationContext): Unit = {
    val desc = new ListStateDescriptor[Long]("countState", classOf[Long])
    countState = context.getOperatorStateStore.getListState(desc)
    count = countState.get().asScala.sum
    println(s"initializeState, count is: ${count}")
  }

  override def notifyCheckpointComplete(checkpointId: Long): Unit = {
    println(s"checkpointComplete, checkpointId: $checkpointId")
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I tried running your code, but since I don't have hdfs, I changed the checkpoint location to `file:///tmp/flink-savepoint/FlinkKafkaTest-checkpoint` -- and it worked perfectly. I tried having it checkpoint to a dir it didn't have permissions for, and the checkpoints never completed. I tried having it checkpoint to hdfs, and it failed because I don't have the hadoop libraries. Sorry that's not very helpful; no idea what the problem might be.

Comment: My experiments were with Flink 1.9; I overlooked that you are using Flink 1.3. There were problems with 1.3.0 -- have you tried upgrading to at least 1.3.3?

Comment: thanks @DavidAnderson for the kind help and effort. I am using the Flink that is deployed by the company team. I will ask them，hope the problem could be found

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I tried open sourced flink 1.3.0 and open sourced 1.7.2. 1.3.0 doesn't write any checkpoint data on HDFS,but 1.7.2 works perfectly. So that, It looks that Flink 1.3.0 has bugs when writing checkpoint data to HDFS.

Comment: Is there a bug report there for 1.3.0?

Comment: The 1.3.x series is no longer supported by the community, but there were 1.3.1, 1.3.2, and 1.3.3 bug fix releases. You could look in Jira -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK -- to try to figure out when this was fixed.

Comment: FYI, there are multiple bug fixes related to checkpointing in 1.3.1 and 1.3.2. Can't tell if they relate to your situation or not. See the release notes for details.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson. I tried open sourced flink v1.3.3, and use the code in my question, there is still nothing written in the directory: $checkpointDirectory/$jobId